# How to write a MATLAB code for this kind of Heaviside step function?

Tags: matlab

To solve one dimensional advection equation denoted by

u_t+u_x = 0,  u=u(x,t), and i.c. u(x,0)= 1+H(x+1)+H(x-1)

using Lax Wanderoff method,
 I need to write a Heaviside step function H(x) and it needs to be zero when x <= 0, 1 when x>0 . The problem is I also need to use that function writing H(x-t+1), H(x-t-1) as I will compare what I find by the exact solution:

u(x,t) =1 +  H(x-t+1) -H(x-t-1)

Here, the "x" and "t" are vectors such that;

`x=-5:0.05:5`

`t=0:0.05:1`

I wrote the Heaviside step function as the following; however, I need it without the for loop.

```
L=length(x)

function H_X= heavisidefunc(x,L)
H_X=zeros(1,L);
for i= 1:L
    if x(i)<= 0
        H_X(i)=0;
    else
        H_X(i)=1;
    end
end
end
```

I get "Dimensions must agree." error if I write

```
H_X3 = heavisidefunc(x-t+1,L);
H_X4 = heavisidefunc(x-t-1,L);
```

Comment: `x` has size 1x201, and `t` has size 1x21, so you cannot do `x-t`. What result would you expect from that operation?

Comment: @LuisMendo I try to somehow represent what the symbolic H(x-t-1) and H(x-t+1) does. Actually, I try to write the initial condition given in homework U_init=1+ H(x-t-1) -H(x-t+1) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution. My new Heaviside function is;

```
function H_X= heavisidefunc(x)

    if x<= 0
        H_X=0;
    else
        H_X=1;
    end
end
```

The problem I had was because I was storing the output as a vector and it just complicated things.
Now,writing H(x-t+1), H(x-t-1) is easier. Just put "heavisidefunc(x(i)-t(j)-1)" and loop from 1 to the length of x and l in two loops. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The Heavyside function is really easy to program in Matlab

```
Heavyside=@(x) x>= 0;
```

The easiest way to get rid of the dimensions must agree error is to transpose one of the vectors. This will cause Matlab to construct a matrix of `length(x1)` by `length(x2)`

```
Heavyside(x-t'+1);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'am wrong, when x is a vector can I give it in a function handle as you did?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to use it in that way. When it's an argument, it's treated as a local variable